# Do you have to us ng-Controller in the view or can you just declare it in the $routeProvider?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

I recently realized I had not used ng-Controller to declare the official scope of my controller in the HTML but had only mentioned it in $routeProvider and all APPEARS to be well.

Does any one know any disadvantage to leaving it as such?  Only defining and the making reference to my controller in the $routeProvider?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would consider it correct, and an advantage the way you have done it, because it better relates the context of your view and bound controller by keeping things in the one place.

Just bear in mind that providing your controller in the route definition is basically the same as putting an `ng-controller="MyCtrl"` inside the element containing your `ng-view` directive that matches your route view.

Also, if you need more complex routing (eg: hierarchical views and controllers), then I would consider looking at [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) to use instead of `ngRoute`

Answer (score 1):

If you're not rendering that HTML from a different place somehow (which I haven't seen happening thus far) then there's no difference, just make sure you're not declaring it twice by accident (once in the $routeProvider and another in the HTML).

Answer (score 1):

You should only declare the controller in your $routeProvider. Otherwise, it will be instanciated twice.

In some case it would be transparent but it can easily lead to bugous behaviour.

As a reference, the Angular guide provides code samples about how do use ng-view: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView

Comment: He doesn't have to declare it in the $routeProvider. I do all my declarations in the HTML itself, it's not a bad usage.

Comment: @OmriAharon I don't know how one can do that (declaring your ng-routes from HTML), can you point me to some samples(links, blogs, jsfiddle) ?

Comment: @BiAiB You declare your routes normally except you leave out the controller. In your views you use the [ng-controller directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController)

Comment: @BiAiB Like Andy said, I was referring to the controller declarations only.